# Delete cross-sell links programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, delete, cross-sells

I have a problem concerning the cross-sell links. I'm building a custom module and I need to add and delete cross-sell links according to a product.

I know how to create the cross-sell links using:

```
$product->setCrossSellLinkData($params);
$product->save();
```

But what I don't know is how to remove cross-sell links.

Is there a function to do that or have I to execute an SQL request to delete the links from `magentocatalog_product_link` inside my module (which isn't a good practice) ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:

Get cross sell product ids:

```
$crossSellLinkData = $product->getCrossSellProductIds();
```

Flip array so that product ids in the array are key values:

```
$crossSellLinkData = array_flip($crossSellLinkData);
```

Then, unset the product you want to remove:

```
unset($crossSellLinkData[product_id]);
```

Then set and save:

```
$product->setCrossSellLinkData($crossSellLinkData);
$product->save();
```