# Removing list of products from up-sells items

Tags: magento-1.9, product, products, product-list, up-sells

I need to remove a list of products from all the up-sells lists; so what I'm doing is checking the IDs of the up-sells products for each product in the database and ideally remove the IDs of the products I don't need anymore and save it.

How can I update the upsells product list or just remove the item I don't want (having its ID)?

Just to avoid some misunderstanding of the problem, below part of the code I wrote:

```
foreach($collection as $p) {
   $upsell = $p->getUpSellProductIds();

   if ( count($upsell) > 0 ) {

      foreach ($upsell as $k => $u) {

         // Check if the entity_id is among the discontinued products
         if ( isset($discontinued[ $u ]) ) {
            // TODO : Remove the discontinued entity from the upsells list
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You want to remove upsell products part from product page?

Comment: If you want to bulk edit upsell then you might take a look at https://github.com/tzyganu/ProductRelationsImport

Comment: No, updating the upsell list in the administration area, just instead of doing it manually I'm creating a script which is using the catalog/product Model -- Mage::getModel('catalog/product')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was related to the way I was trying to save the new data.

Below the right way to save them:

- setUpSellLinkData is the function to use
- $upsellToSave is the array I used to formatting the data for the setUpSellLinkData funciton

  ```
  foreach($collection as $p) {
  $upsell = $p->getUpSellProductIds();

  if ( count($upsell) > 0 ) {
      $toUpdate = false;

      foreach ($upsell as $k => $u) {

          // Check if the entity_id is among the discontinued products
          if ( isset($discontinued[ $u ]) ) {
              // Remove the discontinued entity from the up-sells list
              unset($upsell[$k]);
              $toUpdate = true;
          }
      }

      if ($toUpdate) {
          $upsellToSave = array();

          foreach ($upsell as $u) // Formatting the data
              $upsellToSave[ $u ] = array('position'=>'');

          try {
              $p->setUpSellLinkData($upsellToSave)->save();
          } catch (Exception $e) {
              echo "Problem saving up-sell data.\n";
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Just pasted the code here http://pastebin.com/sMeydZ9A

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sql query :

```
 DELETE l.* FROM catalog_product_link as l
 LEFT JOIN catalog_product_link_type as lt ON (lt.`link_type_id` = l.`link_type_id`)
 WHERE lt.code = "up_sell"
```

Note::Take Database Backup Before doing any database operation.

Below is Magento Code for remove fix upsell item from all products:

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($collection as $p) {
    $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p->getId());
    $upsell = $p->getUpSellProductIds();

    //print_r($upsell);

    $upSellLinkData = array_flip($upsell);

    unset($upSellLinkData[PRODUCT_ID]); - PRODUCT_ID - This is your product id you want to remove from all products 

    //$upSellLinkData = array_flip($upSellLinkData);

    //print_r($upSellLinkData);

    $p->setUpSellLinkData($upSellLinkData);
    $p->save();
    //print_r($upSellLinkData);
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer doing it using the Magento functions. I've added the part of the code I'm stuck with

Comment: Please see updated code.

Comment: I tested the code but seems the changes are not applied.. The up-sell list is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in right direction. You can do it like this:

Get upsell product ids:

**`$upSellLinkData = $product->getUpSellProductIds();`**

Flip array so that product ids in the array are key values:

**`$upSellLinkData = array_flip($upSellLinkData);`**

Then, unset the product you want to remove:

**`unset($upSellLinkData[product_id]);`**

Then set and save:

**`$product->setUpSellLinkData($upSellLinkData);`**

**`$product->save();`**

Please let me know if you find any problem.

You can use above codes in your loop to do it for multiple products.

Reference link: [Delete cross-sell links programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63718/delete-cross-sell-links-programmatically)

Comment: Is not saving the changes.. The code is not giving any error, but the upsells list still the same.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Still the same, I guess the method 'setUpSellProductIds' doesn't exist :/

Comment: I have not mentioned setUpSellProductIds in my code. Please recheck.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the previous version. The method setUpSellLinkData is the right one, just the way is formatted the array is not the one accepted by that method -- See the final version of the code http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/130802/40598